# How to integrate generated opencv with extra modules into an IntelliJ Java project in Windows 10

Tags: java, opencv, intellij-idea, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I successfully generated `opencv` with extra modules from `opencv_contrib` in version `4.6.0`. As a result, amongst others, I got the library `opencv_java460.dll`, `opencv_core460.dll` and `opencv_460.jar`.
I installed the jar manually using maven in my local repository and referenced it in my Java project's `pom.xml`. Once using the library in my code, I got `UnsatisfiedLinkError` when e.g. using `Mat.eye()` even after calling `System.load(path/to/opencv_core460.dll)` beforehand.

Can somebody please explain how to integrate the generated sources correctly within a Java project in IntelliJ on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by applying the flag `BUILD_FAT_JAVA_LIB` in `CMAKE-GUI` and now it works flawlessly.